# How to Build Open DNP3 Library?

Tags: c++, c++11, network-programming, dnp3, opendnp3

I need to Build the  [Open DNP3 Lib](https://github.com/dnp3/opendnp3)
but the problem coz  there is a lot of .cpp and .h files in the  library and I don't know how the add the lib to a Console C++ Project and build it

Iam a beginner in C++ and any thing will help me ; so fell free to leave any comment if you don't know the exact answer

Comment: I found the documentation on building [literally three clicks](https://dnp3.github.io/docs/guide/3.0.0/build/windows/) from the URL you posted

Comment: thank you for your response...
yes i saw this but i dont know which src files should i give the CMake and what is the bilding binaries

Comment: None. CMake will figure everything out itself and generate a build system, which you can then invoke with `cmake --build` or by invoking the build system yourself.

Comment: yes when I open the CMake App it ask me to specify the source file and the building binaries

Comment: I have no idea what the CMake GUI looks like, but isn't it just asking for the CMakeLists.txt and a directory to use as build directory? The page I linked  also just contains commands you can copypaste

Comment: many thanks my friend
every thing done  well 
7 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========  ( ;